# c++ compile error using set [invalid operands to binary expression ('const Room' and 'const Room')]

Tags: c++, set

i recently started learning c++ using mac and CLion and for some reason I cant work with sets in my class. it throws me this error:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/__functional_base:55:21: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('const Room' and 'const Room')
        {return __x < __y;}
                ~~~ ^ ~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/__tree:1928:17: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::__1::less<Room>::operator()' requested here
            if (value_comp()(__v, __nd->__value_))
                ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/__tree:2339:36: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::__1::__tree<Room, std::__1::less<Room>, std::__1::allocator<Room> >::__find_leaf_high' requested here
    __node_base_pointer& __child = __find_leaf_high(__parent, _NodeTypes::__get_key(__nd->__value_));
                                   ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/__tree:1647:17: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::__1::__tree<Room, std::__1::less<Room>, std::__1::allocator<Room> >::__node_insert_multi' requested here
                __node_insert_multi(__cache);
                ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/__tree:1575:9: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__1::__tree<Room, std::__1::less<Room>, std::__1::allocator<Room> >::__assign_multi<std::__1::__tree_const_iterator<Room, std::__1::__tree_node<Room, void *> *, long> >' requested here
        __assign_multi(__t.begin(), __t.end());
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/set:485:21: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::__1::__tree<Room, std::__1::less<Room>, std::__1::allocator<Room> >::operator=' requested here
            __tree_ = __s.__tree_;
                    ^
/Users/janschmutz/CLionProjects/routing/dataModel/Room.h:23:30: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::__1::set<Room, std::__1::less<Room>, std::__1::allocator<Room> >::operator=' requested here
        this->connectedRooms = connectedRooms;
                             ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/utility:567:1: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'pair<type-parameter-0-0, type-parameter-0-1>' against 'const Room'
operator< (const pair<_T1,_T2>& __x, const pair<_T1,_T2>& __y)
```

If i change the set to a vector the code works, what am I doing wrong here? this is the entire Code im using:
Room.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

class Room {
private:
    long id;
    float level;
    string name;
    set<Room> connectedRooms= {};
public:
    Room(long &id, float &level, set<Room> &connectedRooms) {
        this->id = id;
        this->level = level;
        this->connectedRooms = connectedRooms;
    }
    Room() = default;
};
```

Comment: If you are writing C++, you probably should not tag `c` too. The languages are very different in many aspects.

Comment: The error is pretty clear: your `Room` class does not have an associated `operator<`.

Comment: Also, a note - `std::set` will store copies of objects. If you want a tree-like structrue (one room as root, and all the rest connected to that one through other rooms), then it's fine (provided you will build it from leaves), but if you want to be able to traverse from room 1 to 2 and from 2 to 1, then you will be in trouble.

Comment: thanks guys, you just had to implement a < operator!